# VALIDATION_ERROR : "Field is invalid in a request"

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create agreement using paypal rest api.

> POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements

In the request body i am passing "agreement_details" and other required fields such as name , description etc as per the documentation.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#agreement_create

```
"agreement_details": {
    "outstanding_balance": {
      "value": "0.00"
    },
    "cycles_remaining": "4",
    "cycles_completed": "0",
    "final_payment_date": "2016-12-22T20:53:43Z",
    "failed_payment_count": "0"
  }
```

> Status: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "agreement_details",
      "issue": "Field is invalid in a request."
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid request. See details.",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "debug_id": "2fcb57fb9581f"
}
```

Comment: try adding
`"outstanding_balance": {
      "value": "0.00",
      "currency" : "USD"
    }`

Comment: Still the same response. According to my understanding even though they have mentioned some of the fields like "agreement_details" , they are not expecting them as a part of request itself.

Comment: I have made demo in this library. you can use it [https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library)